# Prolog road crossing

Tags: prolog, artificial-intelligence

How can I implement a solution to this problem in Prolog?

> There are 3 dogs and 3 cats on the West side of the road. If at any point there are more dogs than cats on one side (except 0 cats), the dogs will eat the cats. If you can only carry 2 animals at a time across the road, and you can't cross empty-handed, how do you get all animals safely to the East side of the road (shortest path)?
>
> Dogs are interchangeable with each other, and same with cats.

Comment: "*At any point 10 different things can be done*" - 1 cross with a cat, 2 cross with a dog, 3 cross with two cats, 4 cross with two dogs, 5 cross with a mixed pair. Can't cross with nothing, can't carry more than two things, can't carry things from the side you aren't on ... what are the other five things you could do?

Answer (score 2):

```
% state(person on side, animals west, animals east)
initial_state(state(west, cats_dogs(3, 3), cats_dogs(0, 0))).
desired_state(state(east, cats_dogs(0, 0), cats_dogs(3, 3))).

solve(Path) :-
    initial_state(Initial),
    desired_state(Desired),
    % Use iterative deepening for convenience, so no need to guard against circular states
    length(Path, _),
    path(Initial, Desired, Path).

path(Desired, Desired, []).
path(Initial, Desired, [State1|Path]) :-
    move(Initial, State1),
    path(State1, Desired, Path).

road_side(west).
road_side(east).

% Map east & west onto this and other sides
cats_dogs_side(west, W, E, W, E).
cats_dogs_side(east, W, E, E, W).

move(Initial, State1) :-
    Initial = state(HumanSide, West, East),
    % Change from west & east to this and other, in terms of sides
    cats_dogs_side(HumanSide, West, East, This, Other),
    cats_dogs_move(This, Other, This1, Other1),
    % Human moves to other side
    dif(HumanSide, HumanSide1),
    road_side(HumanSide1),
    % Change back to west & east sides, for state-representation consistency
    cats_dogs_side(HumanSide, This1, Other1, West1, East1),
    State1 = state(HumanSide1, West1, East1).

cats_dogs_move(This, Other, This1, Other1) :-
    between(1, 2, AnimalsToMove),
    between(0, AnimalsToMove, CatsToMove),
    DogsToMove is AnimalsToMove - CatsToMove,
    move_safe(This, Other, CatsToMove, DogsToMove, This1, Other1).

move_safe(This, Other, CatsToMove, DogsToMove, This1, Other1) :-
    shift_animals(-1, CatsToMove, DogsToMove, This, This1),
    shift_animals(1, CatsToMove, DogsToMove, Other, Other1),
    safe_cats_dogs(This1),
    safe_cats_dogs(Other1).

shift_animals(Sign, CatsToMove, DogsToMove, cats_dogs(Cats, Dogs), cats_dogs(Cats1, Dogs1)) :-
    Cats1 is Cats + (Sign * CatsToMove),
    Cats1 >= 0,
    Dogs1 is Dogs + (Sign * DogsToMove),
    Dogs1 >= 0.

% Check that side is safe
safe_cats_dogs(cats_dogs(Cats, Dogs)) :-
    (   Dogs > Cats,
        Cats > 0
    ->  false
    ;   true ).
```

Result in swi-prolog (first 2):

```
?- time(solve(Path)).
% 2,287,324 inferences, 0.245 CPU in 0.242 seconds (101% CPU, 9329359 Lips)
Path = [state(east,cats_dogs(3,1),cats_dogs(0,2)),state(west,cats_dogs(3,2),cats_dogs(0,1)),state(east,cats_dogs(3,0),cats_dogs(0,3)),state(west,cats_dogs(3,1),cats_dogs(0,2)),state(east,cats_dogs(1,1),cats_dogs(2,2)),state(west,cats_dogs(2,2),cats_dogs(1,1)),state(east,cats_dogs(0,2),cats_dogs(3,1)),state(west,cats_dogs(0,3),cats_dogs(3,0)),state(east,cats_dogs(0,1),cats_dogs(3,2)),state(west,cats_dogs(0,2),cats_dogs(3,1)),state(east,cats_dogs(0,0),cats_dogs(3,3))] ;
% 328 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (100% CPU, 1197565 Lips)
Path = [state(east,cats_dogs(3,1),cats_dogs(0,2)),state(west,cats_dogs(3,2),cats_dogs(0,1)),state(east,cats_dogs(3,0),cats_dogs(0,3)),state(west,cats_dogs(3,1),cats_dogs(0,2)),state(east,cats_dogs(1,1),cats_dogs(2,2)),state(west,cats_dogs(2,2),cats_dogs(1,1)),state(east,cats_dogs(0,2),cats_dogs(3,1)),state(west,cats_dogs(0,3),cats_dogs(3,0)),state(east,cats_dogs(0,1),cats_dogs(3,2)),state(west,cats_dogs(1,1),cats_dogs(2,2)),state(east,cats_dogs(0,0),cats_dogs(3,3))] ;
```